# How to connect to JMX service on Glassfish from within an EJB?

Tags: glassfish, ejb, jms, jmx

I have a message-driven EJB deployed to a Glassfish 2.x system.  When I get a message that causes an exception or isn't able to be sent or consumed, I would like to do one of the following things:

1. Pause the EJB's subscription to the Topic/Queue
2. Shut down the EJB itself
3. Cease consuming messages until I give an 'all clear' or something equivalent

This is all so that I can stop repeatedly throwing exceptions after calling `context.setRollbackOnly()` on the message.

I've tried connecting to the server via JMX, but from [what I've looked at](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html) in documentation says that I'd have to persist:

- username
- password
- jmx url

in my EJB somewhere.  **Can't I access the JMX server from within the EJB in Glassfish** without having to know that?

Comment: username and password for the JMS Broker?

Comment: Probably not still a valid question but are you trying to connect to JMX in the outer classloader?  You could enable remote JMX connections there and connect over TCP using a JMX client.